# Not able to enter text in a text box using protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I'm trying to click on a text box and enter a text. However protractor is not able to find the element. Here is my what i'm trying to do :

```
 const tenantName = element(by.xpath("//*[@id='j_id0:j_id8:tenantName']"));
 tenantName.click();
 tenantName.sendKeys("tala1");;
```

I get the error :

> No element found using locator: By(xpath, //*[@id='j_id0:j_id8:tenantName'])

I have tried the full xpath also. I get the same error.

Here is the HTML code :

```
<div id="render">                   
   <div class="slds-form slds-form_compound">
     <fieldset class="slds-form-element">
        <div class="slds-form-element__group">
           <div class="slds-form-element__row">
              <div class="slds-form-element slds-size_1-of-2">
                 <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="tenantName">Tenant Name</label><input id="j_id0:j_id8:tenantName" type="text" name="j_id0:j_id8:tenantName" value="test" class="slds-input" required="required" maxlength="50">
```

Comment: is that the actual html? or did you omit closing tags to keep the question short?

Comment: I have omitted the html to keep the question short.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried retrieving the element using other selectors?

Try:

```
element(by.id('j_id0:j_id8:tenantName'))
```

**OR**

```
element(by.css('input#j_id0:j_id8:tenantName'))
```